# Using pipeline.invoke to get full information from new-moverequest

Tags: vb.net, powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I'm writing a .Net script that initiates a local move request on Exchange2010.

I take the output of the script to fill a datagrid showing some details of the newly initiated move request.

This is the script I use:

```
"New-MoveRequest -Identity 'user1' -TargetDatabase 'Mailbox Db1'"
```

At first I used `powershell.invoke` to run the `new-moverequest`.
It returned a nice list with over 91 lines of information about the move request. (returned `line 1 startswith'ModuleTypeName'`)

But I want to use `pipeline.invoke` to run the exact same `new-moverequest`.
This however just returns only 3 lines of information about the move request. This is the same information that you see when you start a new moverequest from the console itself. (returned `line 1 startswith 'Displayname`)

My question:

How can I use pipeline.invoke, but still get the 91 lines of information returned (that I get when using `powershell.invoke`)?